# Spring Data REST findBy multiple Columns

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, spring-data-rest

Is there any way to simplify the following Method Signature for a Spring Data REST Interface?:

```
Page<Account> findAllByAccountIdAndFiscalYearStartAndAccountNumberIgnoreCaseContainingOrAccountCaptionIgnoreCaseContainingOrAccountCaptionDetailIgnoreCaseContaining(
      long AccountId,
      @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE) LocalDate fiscalYearStart,
      @Param("accountNumber") String accountNumber,
      @Param("accountCaption") String accountCaption,
      @Param("accountCaptionDetail") String accountCaptionDetail,
      Pageable page)
```

Comment: No other way to simplify.

Comment: If you mean "make the method name shorter", then an explicit `@Query` would be more readable. The query generation from method name is handy for *simple* queries.

Comment: Another approach is to use a default method which delegates to the long name method.  The long name method is still visible of course, but by convention other code uses the short method name.